# Finding integer value of possible combinations in a multi-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this multi-dimensional array.

```
var multiArray = [
   ['steak tips', 'burgers'],
   ['ice cream', 'cake', 'cookies'],
   ['corona', 'jack daniels']
]
```

I am looking for a function that can somehow calculate the total amount of possible combinations for the following use case:

Print one word from the first nested array, one word from the second nested array, and one word from the third nested array.

I am simply hoping to end up with just an integer result that tells me how many possible solutions there are. It does NOT have to actually go about printing all of these possible combinations to the screen, or anything like that.

Comment: is this a homework assignment?

Comment: No, I am trying to step up my game with trying to manipulate data, it isn't my strong suit. I am trying to get better at it, so I came up with this example. I've kind of just been picking pieces of interview questions off the internet to test myself.

Comment: Make three nested for-loops and you have an O(n^3) solution

Comment: @Matt_Q_247 Please let us know if the suggested duplicate fully addresses your questions

Comment: Not really. I actually should have said that the solution should not involve recursion. I guess all I was looking for was not even a function that prints out the possible values, I was just hoping to produce an integer result that would just tell me how many possible combinations there are. I can worry about actually printing the results at a later time. Let me know if this qualifies for it's own thread or not, I will gladly revise or remove it if needed.

Comment: @Matt_Q_247 If you include `@name` in your comment, that user gets notified of your reply. Now, regarding your question: As it stands, it is a duplicate. But from your last comments it follows that you actually wanted to ask an entirely different question. Then please edit your question to fit your needs. Also: A solution with nested loops doesn't scale to a variable number of arrays.

Comment: Can you include the `javascript` that you have tried to solve inquiry at Question?

Comment: @Matt_Q_247 hm, you basically solved your problem already on your [previous, now deleted question here -> see the first for-loop](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:14-fTB0OmbcJ:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44297549/javascript-multi-dimensional-array-traversal+)

Comment: I deleted it because it's not my code, I still don't understand how that one works at all, it's a little complex for me.

Comment: Let me know if my answer below is unclear or if you prefer a loop-solution by commenting on it and I will explain it in more detail if you wish.

Comment: I mean honestly, I think I'm in a little over my head and need to do some research on reduce, and all of this stuff. That solution below I will have to look into how the reduce function works.

Comment: @Matt_Q_247 I added a code snippet to my answer containing the simplest approach and gradually more complex solutions. I hope this helps you to understand the more complex ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple problem which basically asks for the product of the lengths of an arbitrary number of arrays has an elegant generic solution using the [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce?v=control) method:

```js
function numCombinations(...arrays) {
  return arrays.reduce((prod, array) => prod * array.length, 1);
}

// Examples:
console.log(numCombinations([1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6])); // 6
console.log(numCombinations([1, 2]));                 // 2
console.log(numCombinations([1], []));                // 0
```

We need to specify an initial value of `1` which is the identity element of multiplication.

Appendix: Alternative, exemplary solutions:

```js
// Expects three arrays, returns the product of their lengths:
function numCombinations1(array1, array2, array3) {
  return array1.length * array2.length * array3.length;
}

console.log(numCombinations1([1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6])); // 6

// Expects one array containing the three arrays:
function numCombinations2(arrays) {
  return arrays[0].length * arrays[1].length * arrays[2].length;
}

console.log(numCombinations2([[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6]])); // 6

// Expects one array containing a variable number of arrays:
function numCombinations3(arrays) {
  var product = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
    product = product * arrays[i].length;
  }
  return product;
}

console.log(numCombinations3([[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6]])); // 6

// Replaced traditional for-loop with simpler for-of loop:
function numCombinations4(arrays) {
  var product = 1;
  for (var array of arrays) {
    product *= array.length;
  }
  return product;
}

console.log(numCombinations4([[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6]])); // 6

// Expects a variable number of array arguments using rest parasmeter syntax (...):
function numCombinations5(...arrays) {
  var product = 1;
  for (var array of arrays) {
    product *= array.length;
  }
  return product;
}

console.log(numCombinations5([1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6])); // 6

// Replaced for-of loop with Array.reduce:
function numCombinations6(...arrays) {
  return arrays.reduce(function (product, array) {
    return product * array.length;
  }, 1);
}

console.log(numCombinations6([1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6])); // 6

// Replaced Array.reduce callback function with shorter arrow function:
function numCombinations7(...arrays) {
  return arrays.reduce((product, array) => product * array.length, 1);
}

console.log(numCombinations7([1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6])); // 6
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will take a look into all this tomorrow. I stopped coding for the night because my brain is going to explode. Truly appreciate it, and will comment back.